# Move view upwards when edit text expand

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity called ChatWindowActivity. The layout for this is like chat window in Facebook Messenger. The problem is when edit text is expand to multiple lines, I want the recycler view to move up a litlle bit just like Messenger. I have tried using ConstrainLayout to chain view according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922452/change-height-percentage-based-on-another-views-height-in-constraintlayout) but the result is not what I want.

Here is my ***activity_chat_window.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
            android:tint="#000000"/>
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ_friend_avatar"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/civ_friend_avatar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_friend_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stranger"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:text="Active"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/SubStandardColor">

    </TextView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcv_message_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
        </ScrollView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/body"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2"
            >


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_chat_box"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_round_gray"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Nhập tin nhắn..."
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="4"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_send_message"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'll be grateful for your help!!

Comment: I think you don't need to chain `footer` to your `body` just remove the `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/body"` line

Comment: It helped the layout not ridiculous like before but when edit text expand, the rcv doesnt move up